# Ansible Install with pip3 - which is the default ansible.cfg?

Tags: ansible

I have installed ansible on my contril machine (rhel8.3) via pip3 for my current user and would like to figure out which (of the many) existing `ansible.cfg` files is being utilized as default im my scenario.

```
$ find ~ -name ansible.cfg
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/galaxy/data/apb/tests/ansible.cfg
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/galaxy/data/container/tests/ansible.cfg
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_test/_data/ansible.cfg
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_collections/community/vmware/tests/integration/targets/vmware_vm_inventory/ansible.cfg
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_collections/cyberark/conjur/roles/conjur_host_identity/tests/ansible.cfg
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_collections/infinidat/infinibox/playbooks/ansible.cfg
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_collections/netbox/netbox/ansible.cfg
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_collections/sensu/sensu_go/docs/examples/installation/ansible.cfg
```

I tried to run some ad-hoc ping with the `-v` switch in order to get that information, but that did not really deliver. Can anybody point me to the default? I am aware I can always use a local .cfg file but would still understand what is my reference point in this scenario . obviousely there is no `/etc/ansible`

btw. complete Ansible novice here

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned in [docs.ansible.com](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html):

> Changes can be made and used in a configuration file which will be
> searched for in the following order:
>
> - ANSIBLE_CONFIG (environment variable if set)
> - ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
> - ~/.ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
> - /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
>
> Ansible will process the above list and use the first file found, all
> others are ignored.

Comment: thx, none of the mentioned existed though. I created an `~/ansible.cfg` then